# Retrofit2 not using full base url

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is the retrofir builder

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.6:8000/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

But in the Logcat this is what it shows

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.0.6:8000/login
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 64
D/OkHttp: {"device_name":"Galaxy Note8","password":"pgfhvj","scard":"123"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (64-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 419 unknown status http://192.168.0.6:8000/login (595ms)
```

The `/api` is missing from the post.

This is the ApiInterface

```
@POST("/login")
Call<User> LoginUser(
        @Body Login login
);
```

What could be happening?

After removing the slash I get this in the LogCAt

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.0.6:8000/api/loginapi
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 63
D/OkHttp: {"device_name":"Galaxy Note8","password":"jgchj","scard":"124"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (63-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.0.6:8000/login (1310ms)
D/OkHttp: Host: 192.168.0.6:8000
D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 17:03:36 GMT
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.10
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 17:03:36 GMT
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Img3d080NllvVHNpRzhlalVCQzJaa1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZE13NXlkXC9rcjFWaDdFYWYxazdTa1h5QmNXU1Z6TStmRmdQU3RZczRraWpzZGYwVFRkbjRoSFk5OHQwNHNWY3UiLCJtYWMiOiI5NmNhOTQ4YTg0OTRiNjcwOTI5NTM1ODZmODBlYWZlY2MxYzUwNDQyMjQ0NjE2YTkyYjAxOGFiMjAwYjdkMzNlIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 06-Apr-2020 19:03:36 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: unadeca_session=eyJpdiI6ImRxUmdHUlRoUFU3SzByWmhkd1FpR3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT04yMW9kU0NKV0tRNkR6UEpIRUdqTk9weHVJdndUdGk5UkJqRUdPblZ4VXpcL24rd3ZTb2s2VGptYk5oS1NoNjciLCJtYWMiOiJjYWNhZmQ3MzdjNzI5ZmNmODc5MGFhNTg0YTJkMjZmODIyMWVhOTI1MGVjODdlYjg0Yzc5ZGVhMjdjMzkxNzZkIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 06-Apr-2020 19:03:36 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE html>
//a bunch of html
```

The response should be

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "sadmin",
  "lastname": "apellido",
  "maidenname": "apellido2",
  "card": "1111",
  "scard": "123",
  "user_type_id": 1,
  "email": "sadmin@gmail.com",
  "created_at": "2020-03-20 10:28:36",
  "updated_at": "2020-03-20 10:28:36",
  "token": "y0buzTy77BUbj6r..."
}
```

```
String scardI = scardText.getText().toString();
String passwordI = passwordText.getText().toString();
String device_name = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name");

textViewResult.append(scardI + passwordI + device_name);

Login login = new Login(scardI, passwordI, device_name);
Call<User> call = apiInterface.LoginUser(login);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    //stuff in there
}
```

Comment: Try removing "/" in the interface

Comment: @Keshav1234 I had it like that and it wasn't reading it either, I added it to see if that would work

Comment: please post your code where you are trying to call the end point

Comment: @Keshav1234 I removed it and now I get something else

Comment: please post the code which calls the end point

Comment: @Keshav1234 I added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211086/discussion-between-keshav1234-and-nancy).

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `/` from before `login`

```
@POST("login")
Call<User> LoginUser(
        @Body Login login
);
```

Also check if API is working or not with same parameters in Postman, because

```
D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE html>
//a bunch of html
```

this might have error from server-side also.

Comment: I removed the `/` and I'm using a similar program called Insomnia to test the request and the request returns what is expected